# Can socket file descriptors be passed to childprocesses?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, multiprocessing

I'm currently writing a program and it's a multiprocessed server application. My current idea is for each incoming TCP connection I accept it and pass the incoming socet descriptor to a child process created with fork(). Is the socket descriptor the same in both processes or can undefined behaivour occur? It seems like I can read from the incoming socket but not write to it.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine. It used to be common for a server process to listen on a port, accept a connection, and fork off a child to handle just that connection, for example, and you still see it sometimes.

Comment: Although a forking server was not uncommon a while back... there's a reason why the approach was retired and why evented servers and hybrid servers (with a pool of worker processes and threads) is preferred. A forking server is more expensive in terms of resources per client and will likely fail to support a large number of concurrent connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [man accept](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) emphasis mine:

> RETURN VALUE
>
> On success, these system calls return a nonnegative integer that is a
> **file descriptor** for the accepted socket.

From [man fork](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) emphasis mine:

> - The child inherits **copies** of the parent's set of **open file descriptors**. Each file descriptor in the child refers to the same open file description (see open(2)) as the corresponding file descriptor in the parent. This means that the two descriptors share open file status flags, current file offset, and signal-driven I/O attributes (see the description of F_SETOWN and F_SETSIG in fcntl(2)).

Every accepted connection open in parent/server will be exactly the same in child. It would be strange if your child cannot write to it.

Usually server looks like this:

```
while (..) {
     int newconnection = accept(..);
     switch (fork()) {
     case 0:
         child_handle_connection(newconnection);
         break;
     ...
     }
     close(newconnection);
     ....
 }
```

Comparison: first result I got from google on 'example http server C' results in [this source file](https://gist.github.com/laobubu/d6d0e9beb934b60b2e552c2d03e1409e#file-httpd-c-L54).